# How intercept mouse device with Python for Games?

Tags: python, mouseevent, pywin32, pyautogui

I trying to move my mouse inside an FPS game (like valorant/csgo) but doesn't work.
I used PyAutoGui, PyInput, Mouse, PyWin32, and many other libs but I just can simulate a click.
I see something about Interception (by [oblitum](https://github.com/oblitum/Interception)) and years ago worked but this day doesn't. The game block this intercept.

**So I guess I need to build some driver intercept to make moves in Mouse**. Another trick is to use Arduino (this works these days) but for my project this isn't a solution. I need to only in python with any mouse.

Comment: What game are you trying to create an aim bot for? Anyways, you do not appear to be asking a question. You already seem to know that creating a driver will fool the game. What specific problem do you have?

Comment: The game is Valorant. My question is how intercept a driver using Python or another way to simulate mouse movements in Valorant.

Comment: So you think that you can cheat Valorant’s Vanguard by digging deeper into the kernel than they do? Have you thought about hardware related solutions, too?

Answer (score 1):

This depends how you want to move your mouse. I'm assuming according to however you want to move it? If so, try the first code as the second code performs based on a series of commands

Have you tried [this](https://github.com/flipeador/Python-Interception-Driver) code by @flipeador?

```
#from interception import Interception, MouseFilter, KeyFilter, MouseFlags,\
#    MouseState, KeyState, MapVk, Vk, map_virtual_key

RUNNING = True
TIMEOUT = 2500 # ms

interception = Interception()

interception.set_mouse_filter(MouseFilter.ButtonAll)
interception.set_keyboard_filter(KeyFilter.All)

while RUNNING:
    device = interception.wait_receive(TIMEOUT)

    if device:
        print(f'{device.get_hardware_id()}:')

        # Mouse
        if device.is_mouse:
            print('MouseStroke(flags={1},state={2},rolling={0.rolling},x={0.x},y={0.y},info={0.info})'
                  .format(device.stroke, MouseFlags(device.stroke.flags).name, MouseState(device.stroke.state).name))

        # Keyboard
        elif device.is_keyboard:
            vk = map_virtual_key(device.stroke.code, MapVk.ScToVk)
            print('KeyStroke(sc={0.code:03X},vk={2:03X},state={1},info={0.info})'
                  .format(device.stroke, KeyState(device.stroke.state).name, vk))
            # escape = terminate
            if vk == Vk.Escape:
                RUNNING = False
            # switch x and y
            elif vk == Vk.X:
                device.stroke.code = map_virtual_key(Vk.Y, MapVk.VkToSc)
            elif vk == Vk.Y:
                device.stroke.code = map_virtual_key(Vk.X, MapVk.VkToSc)

        device.send()
        print('-'*100)
```

Do note that you are **not** allowed to cheat in Valorant, as it blocks a lot of "hacking" and detect if your hacking even if the program your using is not on their block list.

Comment: I tried "Interception", but valorant block too. Selenium is for web and, if I no wrong, any movements maybe use mouse_event from ctypes, and that not work too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not here to question your morality.
Definitely go the arduino(s) route (you may need two. One to receive python commands and one to emulate the mouse events. Depends on the arduino) and be sure to use some randomization everywhere.

I do question why you'd want this.
I see no fun in cheating and I can't see what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Thanks but vanguard block ahk too.

Comment: I'm build a bot to perform actions/movements ingame and record, to make clips. Tiktok/Youtube/etc. But thank you, I will try the arduino.